# Android - Unable to parse Remote Message from FCM

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, bundle

I am developing an Android application in which I would like to receive push notification by FCM.

The `onMessageReceived` callback is triggered but the `RemoteMessage.getData()` has returned `null` value and when I evaluated the expression , the `RemoteMessage.mBundle` has the required data but not in JSON format

The following is the data I am getting from `RemoteMessage.mBundle`

```
Bundle[{google.sent_time=1519016906113, gcm.notification.categoryId=80302, google.ttl=2419200, gcm.notification.notificationId=127647, gcm.notification.e=1, gcm.notification.threadId=127093, gcm.notification.title=Moni Expert has commented on your post, from=612005318045, gcm.notification.roleId=115442, gcm.notification.userId=76284, gcm.notification.profileUrl=/image/user_male_portrait?img_id=122306&img_id_token=%2B99KTi28KTf7%2BehhVakxUyPqAuU%3D&t=1519016037919, google.message_id=0:1519016906118429%c05b1316c05b1316, gcm.notification.lastName=Expert, gcm.notification.notificationDate=2018-02-19 05:07:17.821, gcm.notification.timeStamp=Fri Feb 16 14:57:08 GMT 2018, gcm.notification.body=Moni Expert has commented on your post, gcm.notification.flag=0, gcm.notification.type=1, gcm.notification.firstName=Moni, gcm.notification.threadStatus=Published, gcm.notification.subject=posted, gcm.notification.roleName=D4E Admin, gcm.notification.userName=moniexpert, gcm.notification.postedUserId=76284, collapse_key=digital.engineers.club, gcm.notification.notification=Moni Expert has commented on your post}]
```

I have searched a lot to convert this data to `Json` format but nothing helped.

Update :

The code snippet has mentioned below

```
public class D4EPushService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFMService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Handle data payload of FCM messages.
        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Message Id: " + remoteMessage.getMessageId());
        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Notification Message: " +
                remoteMessage.getNotification());
        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Data Message: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        remoteMessage.mBundle;
    }
```

I am not able to even assign `remoteMessage.mBundle` to new bundle variable in my code snippet as it has privately declared in `RemoteMessage` class

Please anyone help me to find the solution.

Comment: paste your code

Comment: Please look at my updated Post.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `data` message payload instead of the `notification` message payload? How are you sending the message?

Comment: in which method your are sending the message ? please paste the structure of the sending message

Comment: // Check if message contains a notification payload.
  `if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }` try this

Comment: @Rahul, thx for your comment . Based on the comment by AL , I could understand that the issue is when sending messages from backend

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution it is work for me.

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {


    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    String message = data.get("your key");}
```